# How to find out what the first view controller that gets loaded in an iPhone app is?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4

I think that looking at others' code is a good way to learn. I'm trying to learn iOS programming like this, but one thing that's confusing is when I look at a new project there's always a bunch of view controllers, and I don't know which one loads first.

Is there an entry in the plist file which says which view controller gets loaded first? How do you go about picking apart someone else's code in an Xcode project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the project there's a space called Main Interface / Main Storyboard that looks like this:

> `Target > General > Deployment Info > Main Interface:`

[image]

But if they set it in code, then use ⇧+⌘+F on the project and search for 'rootViewController'.

Comment: In addition to CodaFi's good advice, if they are setting up the root view controller it in code, there's probably also a 90% chance to assume it'll be in the application delegate's implementation `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, so you can start by looking there directly.

Comment: I'd put it at a 105% chance... I don't think there are many bozo's in this world who are bold enough to mess with their main window outside of the delegate.

Comment: If I moved the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method to another file, that file wouldn't become the first one that launches, will it?

Comment: @javascriptninja, EXCELLENT QUESTION.  Put that one up on SO, right this instant!

Comment: It's sort of a rhetorical question. I don't think it would actually make the other file the first one that launches. My point is there might be a better way to find out which one starts first.

Comment: No, that's the point of conforming to UIApplicationDelegate, is to have the initial launch functions called.  It's a great question.  The app delegate is USUALLY the first thing to be called.